# MySQL MyISAM Difference in Count field between Two identical tables

Tags: mysql, myisam

I have the following 2 identical tables, using MySQL:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `DB`.`tblNew`;
CREATE TABLE  `DB`.`tblNew` (
 `NumberPK` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
 `Count` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`NumberPK`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

and

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `DB`.`tblPrev`;
CREATE TABLE  `DB`.`tblPrev` (
 `NumberPK` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
 `Count` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`NumberPK`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

I want to get the difference in the "Count" field between the two tables, based on them joining on the "NumberPK" field.

I have written this query:

```
SELECT
 gvNew.NumberPK
FROM
 tblNew AS gvNew
LEFT OUTER JOIN
 tblPrev AS gvPrev ON gvNew.NumberPK = gvPrev.NumberPK
ORDER BY gvNew.Count - IFNULL(gvPrev.Count, 0) DESC
LIMIT 10
```

in order to get the 10 "NumberPK" records where the difference was greatest.

The problem with this is that MySql must perform a table scan to get the difference in Counts. The join is very efficient as it is on the primary key, and, although with about 50000 records, the results are returned near-instantaneously, I am wondering if the scan (on the tables with two 4-byte fields in each) would be quite as quick with tables between 1-4 million rows.

Or, are there any better ways of doing this?

Thanks in advance,
Tim

Comment: Do you need to consider where the difference is negative?

Comment: Hi @P.Salmon ...no the difference can never be negative...it can be 0, but not negative.

Answer (score 0):

Using the `PRIMARY KEY` in MyISAM is the same as using any other index:  Drill down the index BTree, then do a random lookup into the data.

In your case you need to scan all rows of the *first* table since you cannot predict which 10 will be of interest.  Then lookup *every* row in the other table since, again, you can't tell which 10 will be needed.

Having `INDEX(NumberPK, Count)` will avoid the extra step mentioned above.  Add that to both tables since you can't predict which order the Optimizer will hit the tables.  (With InnoDB, the clustering of the PK would make this index redundant.)

Alternatively... Here is another possibility.

```
SELECT NumberPk, MAX(`Count`) - MIN(`Count`) AS diff
  FROM (
    SELECT * FROM tblNew
    UNION ALL
    SELECT * FROM tblPrev
  ) X
  GROUP BY NumberPk
  ORDER BY diff DESC
  LIMIT 10
```

This gets rid of all the lookups, but adds in a big sort.  So, I cannot predict whether it will be faster.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply. I have dropped the PK on NumberPK, and added the mentioned index on both tables. The query seems to run twice as fast, but I will let some time pass to get more data and more meaningful results. Thanks for your idea though!